# Properties of $xy^2/(x^2+y^4)$ near the origin

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 
 Defined by $$f(x,y)= \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$$ if $x\neq 0,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $$f(x,y)=0$$ if $x=0,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Then

1. it is continuous but not differentiable at origin
2. differentiable at origin
3. has all first order partial derivative at origin.
4. does not have all first order derivatives at origin.

consider the limit $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ along the curve $y=m\sqrt{x}$ we get
lim$$(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)\frac{x^2m^2}{x^2+m^4x^2}=\frac{m^2}{1+m^4}$$ which is different for different values for $m$ hence $f$ is not continuous at origin, so 1 is false, and 2 is clearly false. I have checked that $f_x$ and $f_y$ exists at $(0,0)$ so only $3$ is correct and all others are false. could any one confirm me am I  right? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}x$is found to be 0. Similarly for $y$. So 3 is true and not 4

Comment: thank you aneesh got it. :)